# QPalette changes behavior between two different versions of Windows for QPushBUtton

Tags: qt

This code:

```
QPalette pal = _btn->palette();
pal.setColor(QPalette::Button, QColor(Qt::green));
_btn->setPalette(pal);
```

produce on Windows 2008 Server R2:
[image: QPushButton background color for Windows server 2008]

The same code produce on Windows 8.1
[image]

The expected result must be the first one, but it is not on Windows 8.1

```
pal.setColor(QPalette::Button, QColor(Qt::green));
```

and

```
  pal.setBrush(QPalette::Button, QColor(Qt::green));
```

have no effect.
Win 8.1 is moor recent than Windows 2008 server and something has changed !
Anyone have an idea?

Note 1: I prefer to not use styesheet, this the last solution for me
Note 2: Qt 5.6.1 version,